# IIB sometimes reads garbled text from an Oracle CLOB

Tags: oracle12c, clob, ibm-integration-bus

I have an IIBv10 (fix pack No 19) application which reads a CLOB field from an Oracle (v12) database and stores into a shared `CHARACTER` variable. I also write the variable content into a log. It usually works perfectly but sometimes in some environments I see that the text from the variable is different from the database text (e. g., one character might be different). What can be the reason for that?
It seems to be reproducing sporadically, both in a multi- and a single-instance environment.

Sample code (MY_TABLE has a CLOB field and MY)

```
DECLARE MY_CACHE SHARED ROW;
DECLARE mySelectStatement CHARACTER 'SELECT * FROM  MY_TABLE';
SET MY_CACHE.Item[] = PASSTHRU(mySelectStatement);
```

Comment: Are the 'different' characters multibyte and/or character-set specific, or are you seeing this with even basic (i.e. ASCII) characters? The 'some environments' part suggests maybe just different locale/character set settings somewhere in the stack, but it depends exactly what is being changed.

Comment: I actually see it with ASCII characters but the text contains multibyte (Cyrillic) characters, too. For instance,
<xs:restriction>blablabla КИРИЛЛИЧЕСКИЕ БУКВЫ</xs:restriction> turns into <xs:restrictton>blablabla КИРИЛЛИЧЕСКИЕ БУКВЫ</xs:restriction> 
(i turns into t in "restriction")

Comment: how are you connecting to oracle DB....is it odbc or jdbc ? You may have to check if UTF-8 is being used in your settings while connecting.

Comment: I am using ODBC  (which is provided by IBM), and I seem to be using UTF-8 but I'll check, thank you.